# Find max of count items list

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm database on iOS and need to show the max count of office rooms in one building. I created models:

```
class Building: Object {
    dynamic var street: String!
    dynamic var number: Int!

    let offices = List<Office>()
}

class Office: Object {
    dynamic var square: Int!
    dynamic var number: Int!
    dynamic var floor: Int!

    let rooms = List<Room>()
}

class Room: Object {
    dynamic var width: Int!
    dynamic var height: Int!
}
```

How can I find max count of rooms in one building with help @count or @max?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the list of buildings by count of rooms and just take the first element:

```
let soredOffices = soredOffices.sorted { $0.rooms.count > $1.rooms.count }
if let maxNumberOfRooms = soredOffices.first {
    //use maxNumberOfRooms
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With regular arrays it might be something like this:

```
building.value(forKeyPath: "offices.@max.rooms.@count")
```

But I am not sure if it will work with `List` type.

Comment: Thank you, but app crashed with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Nested key paths are not supported yet for KVC collection operators.'